# Resetting porcelain tile on Firewall

Tags: tiling

I removed 4x4” porcelain tiles which were glued to the firewall as a shower surround. 
     After I replace the 5/8” firewall With new firewall, can I set the new 6x6” porcelain tiles directly on the face of the firewall with a thinset mortar like TEC 391/398

Comment: What material is the firewall made of?

Comment: Firewall for bathroom surround does not sound right.  ?  Tile on a shower wall should be on a waterproof substrate. Much more info is needed.